# Different game resolutions on emulator and on a real device (which has the same resolution) on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a big problem with game resolution, when I'm running my game on emulator (which theoretically has the same resolution as my real windows phone device: 800 x 480). I'm making the game with Monogame.

Here is how it looks, the bottom of a page when I run the game on emulator:
[image]

And, here is how it looks the bottom of a page, when I run the game on the real device:
[image]

How can I fix this problem? I noticed, that if I hold the back button till I see all the apps that I have opened, and get back to the game, the resolution will be back to normal, as it is on the emulator.

PS> I'm targeting the Windows Phone 8 devices, and testing on a Lumia 520, with Windows 10 Mobile, Preview for developers.

Thanks.

Comment: So the screen is distorted or what ? What do you see on top top of the screen ? black bar ?

Comment: No, the top of the screen is the same on emunator as it is on the device.

Comment: Can you specify what is different about the two images? Is it that on the real device its cut off?

Comment: Then the whole game has to be be distorted in order for that to happen. Could it be because you are not hiding fast enough some sort of task bar in the top ? Try printing out the screen resolution when your Game1() initializes see if it is 800 height or something less.

Comment: I put the following code in the Initialize method, in Game.cs:
`Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Width: " + Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth.ToString() + "\n" + Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight.ToString());
            });`
And it printed out this: http://imgur.com/0oyBZmk
800 x 480 ....

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was caused because I was testing on the Windows 10 Mobile Preview. Today I downgraded to Windows Phone 8.1, and I do not have anymore that problem.